# Cherry 3D printer Nema upgrade

Tags: reprap, nema-17

I'm currently attempting to build the reprap Cherry 3D printer. I'm doing the Nema 17 upgrade for the printer. I realized that the instructions online are optimized for the 28byj-48 stepper motors. Has anyone built this machine with the Nema 17 upgrades and know what size screws would be best to use?

Comment: What kind of e3d hotend is this referng to?

Comment: As there is no reference to anything that might be e3d related, removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Cherry 3D printer with Nema 17 = Small Prusa i3, so the screws are the same M3 with the length you need according your mounting upgrade.